# several ajax calls on submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is this possible?

```
$('form').submit(function(){
            $.post("some.php", { "array": submitedarray}, function(data){
                if(data == "1"){
                    $.post("other.php", function(data){
                        if(data == "1"){
                            alert("zzzzzzzzz");
                        }
                    }

                }else
                    alert("Error!");
            });
            return false;
        });
```

The first ajax call works the second it doesn't how can I make both to work?

Comment: Can you give a few more details about what exactly isn't working?

Comment: the second ajax call: $.post("other.php", function(data){...

Comment: if I replace by alert("sasfvb") it works ok but no ajax...

Answer (score 0):

Yep! Possible.

Check on Ajax Queue [here](http://docs.jquery.com/AjaxQueue)

and [this](http://www.9lessons.info/2011/03/multiple-ajax-requests-with-jquery.html).

Comment: Can someone help me out with a simple example? Thanks